# Django for iOS app with AWS RDS - How to do registration and login with Django REST Framework?

Tags: ios, django, swift, django-rest-framework, registration

I'm building an iOS app, right now it does nothing, I'm implementing the user registration and login first. There's a couple half-implemented features that interact with the database, I've tested them, they work. But right now forget all the things, let's just focus on having proper registration and login for the application.

The backend is Django 1.9, Django REST Framework 3.3, with Amazon Web Services, using Elastic Beanstalk.

I tried googling all of google, tried using multiple methods (aside from using GMail/Facebook for logging in). Using Django-allauth 0.26 right now, and getting status 403 for both registration and logging in. Registration works when using the browser, but not the mobile frontend. Don't know why.

When attempting to login in the browser, a popup pops up saying that the domain (from AWS Elastic Beanstalk) requires a username and password. Part of me is thinking that this is the culprit, but I don't know where this is coming from. I can't find anywhere in AWS that might cause this to popup. I tried all my usernames and passwords, and none of them work.

Please someone help. My time is running out.

**Edit**

**Just go [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/). I should've gone through the tutorial like everyone else, but if you happen to get this problem and happen to read this post, you'll find the answer in the official tutorial and API-Guide in the official website (Right next to the tutorial in the navigation bar of the official website, up top. You can't miss it.)**

Comment: Looks like htpassword, what is url for testing?

Comment: @EminMastizada https://capstone-dev-clone.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/

I can't open it on my computer (just my computer) for some reason. Could be a firewall or something, but I don't have any firewall.

Comment: I can't open too. Are you sure its deployed and running and public? Even ping not works.

Comment: I can't open it, but every other computer I've tried, can. So I don't know what to do with this or what the problem is. I'm most likely going to post about this  in the AWS forums.